# Gemfile syntax error on line 8: unterminated string meets end of file

Tags: heroku, rubygems, syntax-error, gemfile

Getting this error when trying to push gem file to git using git push heroku master.

## A sample Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'puma'
gem 'rails'
gem 'sinatra', '1.0'
gem 'rails_12factor'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
gem 'sinatra’, '1.0'
```

contains a `’` character (i.e. `U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`, a “typographic” or “curly” quote) at the end of `sinatra` rather than a `'` (`U+0027 APOSTROPHE` or “straight” quote), which is causing all the remaining quote characters to be out of alignment.

Changing that character to `'` should fix it.

Comment: good eye, changed that but for some reason still getting the same error

Comment: Added, committed, and pushed?